# iframe style height issue

Tags: css, iframe

I have a webpage with following iframe code.

```
<div style="height: 300px;">
<iframe src="http://www.journaldev.com/wp-content/uploads/jquery/jquery-add.html" 
style="width: 300px;height: 300px;text-align:center;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Problem is that when page loads, iframe size gets converted to 304x154, I am not sure why it's happening. I understand that 4px are getting added because of border, but not sure why height is getting changed to 150px. I want it to be the height I am specifying in style.

My page URL: http://www.journaldev.com/1028/jquery-add-selector-add-element-and-add-html-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<iframe src="http://www.journaldev.com/wp-content/uploads/jquery/jquery-add.html" <br />
style="width: 300px;height: 300px;text-align:center;"></iframe>
```

u use BR tag in the middle of iframe without closing it !

change it to

```
<iframe src="http://www.journaldev.com/wp-content/uploads/jquery/jquery-add.html"
style="width: 300px;height: 300px;text-align:center;"></iframe>
```

as a note:

u dont need to use br tag in your html source file, it will affect after parsing the web page

Comment: thanks, it solved my problem. I use wordpress and didn't noticed the new line in editor. I guess that caused this issue.

Comment: Just curious, is there any CSS property to change the height based on content length, so that scroll bar is not needed.

Comment: u can use overflow: hidden or overflow-y: hidden for removing scroll,
ur question is depending on situation, if ur problem solved u can accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your outer `<div>` is required.

```
<div style="height: 300px;">
<iframe src="http://www.journaldev.com/wp-content/uploads/jquery/jquery-add.html" width="300" height="300" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```